# C++0x using <ratio> for a safer Length-type

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, std

When reading `<ratio>` and `<chrono>` I tried to imagine a `Length`-type that protects against accidental conversion errors.

This is what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>
using namespace std;

template<typename Scale>
struct Length  {
  long long val_;
  Length(long long val) : val_{val} {}
  Length() = default;
  Length(const Length&) = default;
  Length& operator=(const Length&) = default;
  // conversion
  template<typename Scale2>
  Length(const Length<Scale2> &other)
    : val_{ other.val_*(Scale2::num*Scale::den)/(Scale2::den*Scale::num) }
  { }
  // access
  long long value() const { return val_; }
}; 
typedef Length<ratio<1>> m;
typedef Length<kilo> km;
typedef Length<milli> mm;
typedef Length<ratio<1000,1094>> yard;
```

To be used like this

```
int main() {
  km len_km = 300;
  mm len_mm = len_km;
  cout << " millimeter:" << len_mm.value() << endl;
  cout << " m:" << m{len_km}.value() << endl;
  cout << " yd:" << yard{len_km}.value() << endl;
}
```

And now I could add all the `+` and `*` operations to get really comfortable... :-)

I wonder:

- Is there an **easier access to the arithmetic facilities** that `duration` and `time_point` define in `<chrono>` anyway? Can I use those reduce the effort for `Length`?
- The compile-time constant `(Scale2::num*Scale::den)/(Scale2::den*Scale::num)` seems dangerous in the **conversion constructor** (fraction/underflow?), but I can not figure a better metaprogramming way, Any hints here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Is there an **easier access to the
>     arithmetic facilities** that
>     `duration` and `time_point` define in
>     `<chrono>` anyway? Can I use those
>     reduce the effort for `Length`?

For "mixed mode" arithmetic and comparisons you can take advantage of `common_type<T1, T2>::type` for defining return types. `duration` specializes `common_type` to be the greatest common divisor of Period1 and Period2, where Period1 and Period2 are the two `ratio`s involved in an arithmetic or comparison operation.  You might use it like:

```
template <typename Scale1, typename Scale2>
  typename std::common_type<Length<Scale1>, Length<Scale2>>::type
  operator+(Length<Scale1> x, Length<Scale2> y);
```

Unfortunately you'll have to reinvent how to get the greatest common divisor of two `ratio`s at compile time.  Start with compile-time gcd and lcm meta-functions for unsigned long long.

Hmm... or you might be able to base your specialization of `common_type` on the one already done for `duration`.  You could reinterpret the resultant `duration`'s `period` as a scale factor for your `Length`.  I haven't prototyped this, just an idea.

> - The compile-time constant
>     `(Scale2::num*Scale::den)/(Scale2::den*Scale::num)` seems dangerous in the **conversion
>     constructor** (fraction/underflow?),
>     but I can not figure a better
>     metaprogramming way, Any hints here?

Agreed.  `duration` handles this with:

> ```
> template <class Rep2, class Period2>
>   constexpr duration(const duration<Rep2, Period2>& d);
> ```
>
> *Remarks:* This constructor shall not
>   participate in overload resolution
>   unless `treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value` is true or both
>   `ratio_divide<Period2, period>::den` is
>   1 and `treat_as_floating_point<Rep2>::value` is false.
>   [ *Note:* This requirement prevents
>   implicit truncation error when
>   converting between integral-based
>   duration types. Such a construction
>   could easily lead to confusion about
>   the value of the duration. — *end note*]

I.e. you need to `enable_if` your `Length` conversion constructor such that it only exists if the conversion is exact (if you want to base your length on integral types).  For the conversion to be exact, the conversion factor `(Scale2::num*Scale::den)/(Scale2::den*Scale::num)` must be computable without division (except division by 1).  You can use `ratio_divide` to do this division for you, and then the resulting denominator must be 1 (for an exact conversion).

```
enable_if<ratio_divide<Scale2, Scale1>::type::den == 1, ...>
```

This is a great project for learning `ratio`!  Have fun! :-)

Comment: I have this still in my list of fun projects to do. You gave me a good leg-up here. I can follow you in most parts and I agree with needing *gcd*. Doing compile-time *gcd* is quite a challenge for me already, I guess (constexpr can not be recursive, right? Where is the one-line non-recursive loop-free gcd-calculation? *sigh*). I still did not find the time yet. But I will... I will.

Comment: This code is free to use however you want if you just keep the copyright with it: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/ratio

Answer (score 1):

You use an integral type to represent a physical quantity. This is not what people normally want. If you insist on an integral type, at least do the multiplication and division in the right order, that is, all multiplications first and then a division (compare 100*(255/256) and (100*255)/256).

On a related note, bear in mind that of you multiply Length by Length you get an Area, not a Length. Real-life libraries exists that take this into account, see e.g. [siunits](http://home.fnal.gov/~wb/SItempl8.pdf).

Comment: Good point, yes. My intention for the deomstration was to get a single compile-time constant with only one multiplication at runtime. But you are right, that's bad with `int`s here. But I'll leave it at that in the example for now. And, I have heard of the SIUnits-lib and got my inspiration from there. But I just want to explain the new C++0x-Stdlib -- I am trying to find an example for using `<ratio>` without `<chrono>`. You are also correct, I probably would have forgotton only to do `operator*()` with a scalar. Alas, *siunit* did not make it into the new standard. A real pity, isn't it?

Comment: When 100, 255 and 256 are compile-time constants, and you want to minimize the possibility of overflow, then you first want to factor out common factors of the numerator and denominator.  For example the gcd(100, 256) is 4.  So you can divide both 100 and 256 by 4.  Now your problem is (25*255)/64.  This problem can not be further reduced, and so the final answer is (in reduced rational form) 6375/64.  This is what `ratio_divide` does for you, and all at compile time.  Furthermore, if overflow is unavoidable (even with gcd's factored out), you find out at compile time, not run time.